# Adding a share action into a preference screen

Tags: android, preferences, shareactionprovider

I am simply trying to add a ShareAction in my preference screen. I have created a Preference category called share, and I am trying to make it so that when you click on share it brings up the ShareAction. I cannot find anything that explains how to do this thoroughly. If anyone knows a response would be much appreciated.

```
<PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title ="Share"
    >



    <Preference
        android:title="Share"
        android:id="@+id/SharePreference"
        android:key="SharePreference">

    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look for Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html), for **standard way** of Share action provider

I use [Flipboard's bottomsheet](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) library because i like it.

you can implement it this way,

**Library dependency**

```
compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.4.3'
```

**Layout**

```
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<--ADD YOUR ALL VIEWS IN THIS ROOT>

</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

**Decleration**

```
protected BottomSheetLayout bottomSheetLayout;
```

**Initialization**

```
bottomSheetLayout = (BottomSheetLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
```

**Share action button onclick**

```
Preference share= findPreference("shareprefrence");
        share.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your link or text to share");
                        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        IntentPickerSheetView intentPickerSheet = new IntentPickerSheetView(Profile.this, shareIntent, "Share Fitspur with your friends", new IntentPickerSheetView.OnIntentPickedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onIntentPicked(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo activityInfo) {
                                bottomSheetLayout.dismissSheet();
                                startActivity(activityInfo.getConcreteIntent(shareIntent));
                            }
                        });
                        // Filter out built in sharing options such as bluetooth and beam.
                        intentPickerSheet.setFilter(new IntentPickerSheetView.Filter() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean include(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo info) {
                                return !info.componentName.getPackageName().startsWith("com.android");
                            }
                        });
                        // Sort activities in reverse order for no good reason
                        intentPickerSheet.setSortMethod(new Comparator<IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo lhs, IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo rhs) {
                                return rhs.label.compareTo(lhs.label);
                            }
                        });
                        bottomSheetLayout.showWithSheetView(intentPickerSheet);
            return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

[Licence](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: This is in a preference screen though so I don't have a button.

Comment: you can still implement onClickListner on it, share your layout so that i'll be able to tell in more details

Comment: I think you cannot do it from prefrences, you'll have to use menu item or anything else in a view